# An In-memory database solution with quickest real time replication

Tags: database, replication, in-memory-database

We have a 10 thousand row table that has just 2 columns, a primary key and a second column that keep state. The problem is that we need this state to be replicated across 3 physical locations in the US(about 2000 miles apart), in near real time or as fast as practically possible over a network. Any of the 3 locations can update the state for a given row in this table which should be replicated in near real time to the other 2 locations.

Are there any open source or commercial light weight in-memory database that could help us achieve what we are trying to do. Disk persistence is not that important here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Redis](http://redis.io/). Here's the [Replication Howto](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/ReplicationHowto).

Also, if you decide that the DB doesn't absolutely need to be in-memory, it just needs to be fast, you might want to consider [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). It can do continuous replication, which is essentially instant, and all nodes are masters. It has a well-thought-out conflict detection and resolution mechanism. [This blog post](http://blog.couch.io/post/468392274/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-three-new) is a great introduction to the latest and greatest CouchDB replication capabilities.

Comment: He can use CouchDB ( or MongoDB ) on a in-memory filesystem like tmpfs on linux as long as the databae fits in memory...

Answer (score 1):

Though there is no replication support built-in, you can use [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) with an in-memory [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) database. Within the trigger, use a [custom function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to communicate the changes to the other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Altibase](http://www.altibase.com). They said they have the world's fastest in-memory database. They say they are 5 to 10 times faster than most in-memory DBMS and they also have a free trial on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I execute a complex SQL which has more than 6000 rows 10000 times in my Websphere Server. Total net execution  times are like that:

> ```
>           Derby (In Memory)   Oracle(standard DB) SQLite (In Memory)  HSQLDb (In Memory)
>           nano sec.  second    nano sec.  second  nano sec.  second   nano sec. second
> 1. try    58000000    0,058   6149976000   6,1    1141988000   1,14   999403000    1,00
> 2. try    78560000    0,078   5268477000   5,2    1182621000   1,18   1338705000   1,34
> 3. try    58849000    0,058   5200898000   5,2    1133003000   1,13   2239527000   2,24
> 4. try    60901000    0,06    5435216000   5,4    1205442000   1,21   1370711000   1,37
> 5. try    58798000    0,058   6501929000   6,5    1186734000   1,19   1001800000   1,00
> 6. try    62928000    0,062   5913053000   5,9    1224470000   1,22   1066736000   1,07
> 7. try    71171000    0,071   5111207000   5,1    1200769000   1,20   1304524000   1,30
> 8. try    66913000    0,066   5517989000   5,5    1173495000   1,17   1299230000   1,30
> 9. try    58777000    0,058   7209555000   7,2    1179013000   1,18   1031795000   1,03
> 10. try   75299000    0,075   5356514000   5,3    1182715000   1,18   1368461000   1,37
> average   65019600    0,064   5766481400   5,7    1181025000   1,18   1302089200   1,30
> ```

I obviously compare Derby, SQLite and HSQLDB. Oracle isn't a in memory db. But I put it's result to table because to show speed difference between a in memory db and normal db.

PS: In SQLite and HSQLDB result aren't stable. So I choose 10 stable results in 100 try. Sometimes HSQLDB is faster than SQLite. I think theirs performance are same.